# which Postgresql.conf file, which I should I edit for performance tuning?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, configuration

My Postgresql Data is under /mnt/pg_data/9.0/main/.  So, I have two postgresql.conf files. One under /mnt/pg_data/9.0/main/ directory and the other under /etc/postgresql/9.0/main/. Which one should I be editing for performance tuning such as MAXCONNECTIONS and memory utilization and other things?

Answer (score 2):

Why not as postgres:

```
show config_file ;
               config_file                
------------------------------------------
 /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the script that starts Postgresql... For instance if you're under Ubuntu that would be `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.0`. I have 8.3 here so I can't check directly, but my version includes `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`, and that script looks inside `/etc/postgresql/*`.

Answer (score 0):

By default the .conf file with your data will be used, but your init script might be overriding this with a command line switch, so have a look at your distro's documentation for postgres, or failing that examing the init script. Additionally the .conf file may be including other files.